# Change path of phpunit command

Tags: php, powershell, cmd

I installed phpunit via composer but if I typed `phpunit` into cmd It would use old phpunit that was installed with PEAR. So I deleted all phpunit files from PEAR folder and It is still trying to use old phpunit path. How do I change the variable path so It uses the new phpunit installed via composer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**phpunit** is not properly install, there might be a version conflict.

Use like this: In windows, if you using *wamp* and *blog* being my root folder

```
c:/wamp/www/blog/>"vendor/bin/phpunit"
```